# Problem switching hidden value of an input

Tags: jquery

I want to toggle the value of a hidden input, between **advanced** and **normal**?  But the below script doesn't work, nothing happens.

```
$('#advancedLink').click(function () {
  $("#searchType").val($(this).text() == 'normal' ? 'advanced' : 'normal');
  return false;
});
```

However, if I switch place of **normal** and **advanced** it will work one time, but it won't switch back to normal if I click again.

```
$('#advancedLink').click(function () {
  $("#searchType").val($(this).text() == 'normal' ? 'normal' : 'advanced');
  return false;
});
```

But this last way seems rather unintuitive to me. Any ideas?

**EDIT**
This is the rendered HTML

```
<div>
    <div class="left" id="searchControl">
        <a id="advancedLink" href="#">Advanced search</a><br>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" value="normal" name="searchType" id="searchType">
</div>
```

Comment: Could you post the HTML for the link and input?

Comment: Does the `text` value of `advancedLink` ever change? otherwise you're telling your script that "if advancedLink reads 'normal'"... which won't happen, of course

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're checking the value of the link but setting the value for the text box. Since the value of the link never changes, the text box value does not change either.

Here's a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/GKfWB/

```
$('#advancedLink').click(function () {
  $("#searchType").val($('#searchType').val() == 'normal' ? 'advanced' : 'normal');
  console.log($("#searchType").val())
  return false;
});
```

Comment: This helped. Basically the problem was (I think) that `this` didn't reference `#searchType` but `#advancedLink`.

Comment: @Niklas that is correct. Since you're triggering on click `this` refers to the link and not to your hidden element.

Answer (score 1):

try to run:

```
$('#advancedLink').click(function () {
  console.log($(this).text()); 
  return false;
});
```

to see what is going on. probably you'll have to change .text() to .val()

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is even what you're trying to do without some example html. (Try setting up a jsfiddle with your problem)

Here's an attempt to fix the possible problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/JF4tg/

```
$('#advancedLink').click(function () {
    $("#searchType").val(function() {   
        return $(this).val() == 'normal' ? 'advanced' : 'normal';
    });
    return false;
});
```